# Migration from Vue2 to Vue3. Error: Can't resolve 'vue'

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3

I try to migrate from vue2 to vue3 and now I have similar problem in all my components:

```
ERROR in ./app/assets/js/particles/UserButton.vue?vue&type=template&id=4bdecb56&scoped=true&lang=pug (./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2]!./node_modules/vue-pug-loader/index.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[10].use[0]!./app/assets/js/particles/UserButton.vue?vue&type=template&id=4bdecb56&scoped=true&lang=pug) 1:0-391
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' in '/app/app/assets/js/particles'
```

What I have:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@vue/compat": "^3.3.4",
  "vue": "^3.3.4",
  "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.3",
},
```

All my components don't use `setup()` at this moment

Answer (score 2):

One string changes everything!
Just add it in webpack

```js
externals: {
    vue: "Vue",
  },
```

Comment: Glad you got it fixed.  Even though it’s your own answer, it’s helpful to mark it as accepted.